# Showing $ \sum _{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n +(-1)^n} $ is not convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Consider the series
$$ \sum _{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n +(-1)^n} $$

I think it is not convergent. For this purpose I want to show that the partial sums are not bounded. I have tried so much and I think the partial sums are unbounded but I can not persuade myself. I need a good proof to persuade me for unboundedness.

Comment: Can you use some knowledge of Taylor series, say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine the two terms for $n=2k$ and $2k+1$ you get

$$\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{\sqrt{2k}+(-1)^{2k}}+\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{\sqrt{2k+1}+(-1)^{2k+1}}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}-1}$$
This difference is $ \sim -\frac{1}{k}+O(k^{-3/2})\;$ for $k\rightarrow\infty.\;$
Therefore the series diverges like the negative harmonic sum.